# Nesse caso abaixo , o atributo login não teria que ser definido como private para o método?

Tags: java, herança

Estou estudando herança em Java é num dos exercícios tem o código abaixo, acho, o atributo login não teria que ser definido como private para o método?

```
public class Gerente extends Funcionario {

private int senha;

public void setSenha(int senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public boolean autentica(int senha) {
    if(this.senha == senha) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//novo método, recebendo dois params
public boolean autentica(String login, int senha) {
    //implementacao omitida
}
```

}

Comment: Não existe um "atributo" `login` neste código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem um contexto sobre o problema, fica díficil dizer com precisão.

Mas olhando apenas o código, entendo que no momento da autenticação você vai realizar uma comparação entre os valores do Gerente e valores que veio dos parâmetros.

Portanto, o `login`:

```
//novo método, recebendo dois params
public boolean autentica(String login, int senha) {
    //implementacao omitida
}
```

Tal como a senha, já existente no `Gerente`:

```
private int senha;
```

Deve ser sim uma campo privado do `Gerente`. Assim:

```
private String login;
private int senha;
```

Isto porque `login` e `senha` **pertecem** ao `Gerente`.

Então teríamos algo assim, usando o código acima:

```
Gerente gerente = new Gerente();
gerente.setSenha("senha");
gerente.setLogin("login");

boolen loginValido = gerente.autenticar("outroLogin", "outraSenha");
```

Ou, melhor ainda, sem os `sets` e usando construtor:

```
Gerente gerente = new Gerente("login", "senha");
boolen loginValido = gerente.autenticar("outroLogin", "outraSenha");
```

Se quiser evoluir este modelo, geralmente `login` e `senha` são associados a um `Usuario`. Desta forma, seria interessante que `Gerente` tivesse um `Usuario` com login e senha.

Comment: Desculpem a falta de contexto, esqueci de colocar <br/>
os arquivos. Colei meus arquivos no PASTEBIN: <br/>

Funcionario.java --> https://pastebin.com/5xrYHzBS <br/>
Gerente.java ------> https://pastebin.com/ZJ8yMwuJ <br/>
TesteGerente.java -> https://pastebin.com/wmJ5vpUm <br/>
TesteFuncionario --> https://pastebin.com/Pruz1y7j <br/>
<br/>
E mais uma duvida teorica, agradeço a atenção de td!<br/>

Comment: Vi o restante do código e me parece que a solução que propus atende. Se possível, edite sua questão e coloque o código na sua pergunta mesmo.

Comment: @Downvoter, por qual razão votou negativo?

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas infelizmente essa marcaçao "@Downvoter" nao notifica quem votou na pergunta :/

Comment: @Articuno, sim, foi só uma forma de referenciar quem votou negativo, rs

Comment: Eu tb não negativei, mas não consigo positivar, sempre cai para -1

Comment: @weltonvaz, tranquilo. Veja se minha resposta atende.

Comment: Sua resposta foi excelente tirou duvidas que meu instrutor não estava conseguindo ajudar. Valeu obrigado!